# comparing IDs generated from uuid npm package

Tags: javascript, uuid

My function should remove a recipe.

So I am filtering all the recipes only if the ID is not equal to the ID passed as an argument

(We should only remove the recipe if the ID is found on the array)

The IDs were generated using the package uuid (v4 method)

```
const removeRecipe = (id) => {
  const recipes = loadRecipes();
  const recipesToKeep = recipes.filter((recipe) => {
    return recipe.id !== id;
  });

  if (recipes.legth > recipesToKeep.legth) {
    console.log(chalk.green.inverse('Recipe Removed'));
    saveRecipes(recipesToKeep);
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.red.inverse('Recipe not found'));
  }
};
```

The problem is that even when the IDs are equal both in value and type(string), and the filter function should ignore the recipe the function is still returning false

so "c3a76b5b-bc36-4e87-8e2c-229211ca265d" === "c3a76b5b-bc36-4e87-8e2c-229211ca265d" is true and should not be part of the filtered array but it is being evaluated as false

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: And you’re certain it’s not the typos before you save anything? I.e., check your assumptions, and include verification in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a typo on

```
if (recipes.legth > recipesToKeep.legth) {
```

I has to be

```
if (recipes.length > recipesToKeep.length) {
```